# get files from multiple directories

Tags: c#

i am trying to get a list of files into an array or list from multiple directories

currently i am doing:

```
tempbatchaddresses = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.log");
```

but i also need `tempbatchaddresses += Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\", "*.log");`

and a third one as well. i need to add the file locations of files from 3 different directories.

how do i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tempBatchAddresses = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.log").ToList();

tempBatchAddresses.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\", "*.log").ToList());

tempBatchAddresses.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles("some dir", "some pattern").ToList());
```

and so on ..

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
List<string> myFiles = new List<string>();
myFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.log"));
...etc...

foreach (string file in myFiles)
{
    //do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a myriad number of similar ways to tackle the problem. Here's one.

```
static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<string> files = GetFiles("*.log", @"C:\", @"D:\", @"E:\");
}

static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string searchPattern, params string[] directories)
{
    foreach (string directory in directories)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directory, searchPattern))
            yield return file;
    }
}
```