# How to get specific directories for process

Tags: c#

I have a directory which contains many subdirectories. For example:

```
Emp1
 Acc
 profile
   pro1.xml
   pro2.xml
 data
Emp2
 Acc
 profile
   pro1.xml
   pro2.xml
 data
Emp3
 Acc
 profile
   pro1.xml
   pro2.xml
 data
```

I want to write a foreach loop so I get only files which reside in the profile folder. For example:

```
 foreach string filename in directory.getdirectories(filepat){
        //code.
  }
```

Can someone please help me create a search pattern to do this?

Comment: So you want all files from each of the three profile folders? What do you want to do with the files? Add them to a list?

Comment: Maybe a recursive method will be a solution.

Comment: How to get files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466756/get-files-from-multiple-directories (about performances: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831641/more-efficient-method-of-getting-directory-size/9831721#9831721) and how to get executable path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-net-in-a-console-app

Comment: [How to recursively list all the files in a directory in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c) Just check if the `Directory` name is `profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT after Question Edited....

```
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\stackoverflow");
foreach (var element in dinfo.GetDirectories(@"profile", SearchOption.AllDirectories).SelectMany(x => x.GetFiles()))
{
    Console.WriteLine (element);
}
```

Like this?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some fluent extensions to files and directories that let you do this nicely with linq, Take a look here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2011/11/staticvoid-io-extentions-nuget.html

or download from nuget using `Install-Package StaticVoid.Core.IO`

```
diretory.Directories().SelectMany(d => 
   d.Directory(di => di.Name == "Acc")
       .Directory(di => di.Name == "profile").Files());
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be what you want...

```
 string [] dirname = Directory.GetDirectories(path){
                 foreach( string s in dirname)
                 {
                   if(s.Contains("profile"))
                   {
                     //do your work
                   }
                 }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that the starting point is one level up.

Comment: You need the namespaces:
System.Linq
System.Collections.Generic

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like the following:

```
 IEnumerable<string> directories = Directory.GetDirectories("PATH", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => d == "ProfileFolder");
 foreach (string directory in directories)
 {
     string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
 }
```

Comment: system.Linq and System.Collection namespaces I have added and still i can not get intellisence for where keyword.

Comment: Have you added them as using statements as well as adding the references to the project?