# .net filter a directory. Leave only the files included in a list of comma delimited string

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file-io, directory

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714101/quickest-way-in-c-sharp-to-find-a-file-in-a-directory-with-over-20-000-files) SO question but that didn't help. I have a directory with ~10,000 files. I want to delete all of them except the ones that were passed in as a parameter. The parameter value is comma separated file names (w/o paths) e.g. GMTEDC.dll,DirectoryInfo.xml,DBConnService.exe.config,DBConnService.exe,ComponentSpace.SAML.dll

What is the quickest way to delete all but the ones in the parameter? Creating a clone of the existing directory with just those files is also an option. The goal is to keep the selected files in all different folders they are present preserving the folder hierarchy.

I've looked at [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but can't figure out how to get it to do what I need to do other than iterating through each file which takes too long.

Comment: Regardless of how cool your code is, its going to iterate through each file to delete it.  IO is your bottleneck here, not the code.

Comment: How long does it take you to iterate 10,000 files?

Comment: How are you going to compare file names without iterating through each one?

Comment: @paqogomez and Jonesy - GetFiles let you send in a search filter. I haven't tried it but I'm pretty sure I can pass in each file name one at a time and get the result collection that I can iterate through and recreate that folder structure with the files in another folder. I'm hoping there is a way to either pass in all the files at the same time or something similar.

Comment: @Blam - I don't have exact metrics because I'm doing this in a TFS build so I haven't added benchmarking messages but I should and will. I know it needs improvement because the build time went from 1hr to 3.5hrs.

Comment: If you have not benchmarked then how do you know that iterating through each file takes too long?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

---

```
using System.Linq;
...
string[] filesNotDeleteByName = new [] {"filename1.etc", "filename2.etc", ...};

DirectoryInfo yourDirectory = new DirectoryInfo("[PATH_TO_YOUR_DIRECTORY]");
IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = yourDirectory.EnumerateFiles().Where(fileInfo = > !fileNotDeleteByName.Contains(fileInfo.Name.ToLower()));

foreach(FileInfo fileInfo in files)
{
    // Get File Directory
    DirectoryInfo fileDirectory = fileInfo.Directory;

    fileInfo.Delete();

    // Delete Empty Directory ?
    if(!fileDirectory.EnumerateFiles().Any())
    {
        fileDirectory.Delete();
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks Calvjn. I'll give it a try and let you know. I figured this would be easy to do with linq but it's a skill I'm not a black belt in.

Comment: Well Linq with Lambda Expressions are powerful functions.

Comment: This still requires iterating through every file. I think this [SO qts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466756/get-files-from-multiple-directories) has a better option. It's better to iterate through the files I need, get the match using getfiles, aggregate them using addrange and then create a new output directory with just those files. Then delete the original output directory and rename the new one to the output directory. What you do think?